# Найти атрибут name и выполнить действие

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте!

Есть на странице у меня два поля input:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
```

И скрипт, который заполняет эти поля Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function zapolnit_test () {
$("input[name=test]").val('Test');
$("input[name=test1]").val('Test1');
}
</script>
```

Все работает и заполняет. Но бывает так, что на странице вместо двух полей только одно. И при выполнении функции `zapolnit_test` страница вверх прыгает (ошибка).

Как сделать проверку, есть ли поле такое и потом только выполнить `$("input[name=test]").val('Test');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($("input[name=test]").length) {
    $("input[name=test]").val('Test');
}
```

А по хорошему не стоит [повторять](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) схожие действия.

Ваш код можно переписать так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function zapolnit_test (name, value) {
        selector = "input[name=" + name + "]";
        element = $(selector);
        if(element.length) {
            element.val(value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Или даже элемент передавать в функцию

Answer (score 0):

Например, ты хочешь проверить, существует ли input с id, пишешь так:

```
if($("input").is("#someID")) alert ("This Input isset");
else alert("This Input Not Isset");
```